# react fetch response meaning of type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, strapi

While viewing the response using the fetch api in the react app created with create-react-app, the following output occurred.

[image: screenshot]

I don't get the meaning of type in response. I mean, what type?

Since react dev port and strapi port is different, I set proxy configuration in package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:1337"
```

Source code is just a simple fetch request for other port that I'm using with strapi.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST}/contents`, {
        headers: {},
      });
      console.log(result);
    })();
  }, []);
```

What is the meaning of `type` in this response?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for [What is Response.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type)?

Comment: @decpk Wow this is what I needed. Thank you for sure!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @decpk Who commented on my post, finally knew what it means.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type

It literally means the type of response, and
Since I used proxy option for request to cross-origin domain,
the response type meant 'cors' is Response was received from a valid cross-origin request.